# How to debug a malware that does DLL injection into explorer.exe?

Tags: debugging, debuggers, dynamic-analysis, dll-injection

What steps would you suggest for debugging a malware that injects a DLL into explorer.exe?

- using X32dbg
- have already attached explorer.exe to x32dbg

Answer (score 1):

Try to find injector's code.
Determine what is the dll (find related code and dump it).
Read about how dll is loaded in the process (https://mez0.cc/posts/exploring-dll-loads/)
For debug dll you can set breakpoint in DLLMain, when ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACHED.